# How to automatically extend a graphic in height with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a bar plot with so many values, that the default height of the graphic is too small. How to expand the height until all values are readable?

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.sample(200))
s.plot.barh()
plt.savefig("plot.png")
```

[image]

Comment: You can use figsize=(x,y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply adjust the height of the figure so it is proportional to the number of rows/bars that you are plotting:

```
N = 200
s = pd.Series(np.random.sample(N))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,0.25*N))
s.plot.barh(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. Solved. Can you explain me how to add padding left and right to the figure too?

Comment: you can use [`plt.subplots_adjust()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html?highlight=adjust#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust)